# How to retrieve content in PHP from external JavaScript

Tags: javascript, php, json, wordpress, codeigniter

I have an external JavaScript file, I would like to display array content in my PHP page. How can I display the content by loop. I tried to display the content using following code. But Failed.

```
 <?php
 ini_set('allow_url_fopen', 'On');

$feed = file_get_contents("https://example.com/media-list.js");
$array = json_decode($json);
var_dump($array);
$urlPoster=array();
foreach ($array as $value) { 
    $urlPoster[]=$value->urlPoster;
}
print_r($urlPoster);
 ?>
```

media-list.js content

```
var contents = {
    "0W7EHsR8":{
        "attachmentCode":"0W7EHsR8",
        "title":"title1",

    },  

    "vciym7Zb4":{
        "attachmentCode":"vciym7Zb4",
        "title":"title2",

    },  

    "XlKBM6":{
        "attachmentCode":"XlKBM6",
        "title":"Title3",

    }
};
```

I would like to display content like

Title is "title1" .

Title is "title2".

Comment: In my opinion, if you will parse the js object from the URL, you will be able to decode the json object to PHP array.

Comment: Can you please provide a working example

Comment: I will put here the steps, so you can work it out. 
1 - Get the content. (already done)
2 - Parse the content to find the JSON object. (Regular expression will help you here: https://regex101.com/)
3 - decode the found string into a PHP array.

Comment: You state that you want to retrieve something from JavaScript, but JavaScript is a programming language. Are you intending to parse the entire JavaScript program? Comments here appear to assume that you mean JSON, which is **not** the same thing. Please [edit] your question to indicate what you are really wanting. Please include an example of the text in the file which you are trying to read.

Comment: @Farhad$json = file_get_contents('https://wordpresstechy.com/media-list.js');
$array = json_decode($json);
var_dump($array);
$urlPoster=array();
foreach ($array as $value) { 
    $urlPoster[]=$value->urlPoster;
}

print_r($urlPoster); Code not working

Comment: You missed the regular expression step from my previous comments.

Comment: I dont know how to set up this. please help. @Farhad

Comment: If you will need only titles, you can parse only those fields which you need.
Regular expression to get the titles: "title":".*", not tested

Comment: @Farhad Can you share a working code in jsfiddle or any other tool. I need title and attachementcode in loop

Comment: Is it possible to reverse array content {"0W7EHsR8":{"attachmentCode":"0W7EHsR8","title":"title1"},"vciym7Zb4":{"attachmentCode":"vciym7Zb4","title":"title2"},"XlKBM6":{"attachmentCode":"XlKBM6","title":"Title3"}}

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to use `json_decode()` on a Javascript Array. JSON and Javascript are two different things.
You need to convert your `contents` array to JSON, save it in a different file (`contents.json` for example) and load that file with `file_get_contents`.
If you need to do this only once you can do something like

```js
var contents = {
    "0W7EHsR8":{
        "attachmentCode":"0W7EHsR8",
        "title":"title1",

    },  

    "vciym7Zb4":{
        "attachmentCode":"vciym7Zb4",
        "title":"title2",

    },  

    "XlKBM6":{
        "attachmentCode":"XlKBM6",
        "title":"Title3",

    }
};

console.log(JSON.stringify(contents));
```

and copy the result from the console (click CTRL+Shift+I to open it).

`JSON.stringify()` takes a Javascript array and turns it into a JSON string.

for this small array the JSON equivalent is

```
{"0W7EHsR8":{"attachmentCode":"0W7EHsR8","title":"title1"},"vciym7Zb4":{"attachmentCode":"vciym7Zb4","title":"title2"},"XlKBM6":{"attachmentCode":"XlKBM6","title":"Title3"}}
```

If you intend on making this dynamic (say, loading all attachemnts from a database) you can create a php file that loads that data into an array and returns it into proper JSON using json_encode(). Loading that file with file_get_contents and using json_decode like you are doing now should do the trick.

Comment: How can I reverse this array content?

Comment: If you generate your initial array (the one you pass through to json_encode), just use array_reverse() on that. Otherwise, after you've loaded it using file_get_contents and then json_decode, use array_reverse() on that.